# SQL Server to extract if the status is terminated then dont show previous records for that ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help how to write a sql command i have several agents eg from Jan to feb they were active and in March they were terminated.  how to write the query if they are terminated at the last date then don't show me even the prior records for that agent?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: What if they are terminated before the last date?

Answer (score 0):

**If** i understand correctly you need :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.agent = t.agent and t1.status = 'terminated');
```

Comment: Ending AgentNumber Name Agency PayeeID CompPlan Ending_Balance Status
2018-01-02 0002320 Nelson, Michael L 14600 39797 38 -166.82000000000000 A
2018-01-02 0002320 Nelson, Michael L 14600 39797 38 -166.82000000000000 T
2018-01-02 0002320 Nelson, Michael L 14600 39797 38 -166.82000000000000 S
2018-01-08 0002320 Nelson, Michael L 14600 39797 38 -166.82000000000000 S
2018-01-08 0002320 Nelson, Michael L 14600 39797 38 -166.82000000000000 T

Comment: it shows the status of S and T.  I need to be able to if at any point in time the agent were in a status T to exclude that agent all together from the data.  Only pull agents that have never had a status T.

Comment: @nancy7. . . Edit the question with above sample data & desired result instead of posting in comment.